# How to find AUC metric value for keras model?

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, keras

I have wanted to find AUC metric for my Keras model. Keras doesn't have any inbuilt function to measure AUC metric.  So I found that write a function which calculates AUC metric and call this function while compiling Keras model like:

```
from sklearn import metrics
from keras import backend as K

def auc(y_true, y_pred):
    return metrics.roc_auc_score(K.eval(y_true), K.eval(y_pred))     
model.compile(loss="binary_crossentropy", optimizer='adam',metrics=['auc'])
```

But this doesn't work in my case. Please help me to figure out this query.

thanks

Answer (score 3):

There is now a built-in function to compute (an approximation of) the AUC. See [`tf.keras.metrics.AUC`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/metrics/AUC). Apparently, you just need to do the following

```
...
model = tf.keras.Model(inputs, outputs)
model.compile('sgd', loss='mse', metrics=[tf.keras.metrics.AUC()])
```

Comment: Getting `InvalidArgumentError:` while trying to find AUC as mentioned in your answer. Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66207874/tensorflow-invalidargumenterror-while-find-the-auc-score)

Answer (score 1):

I solve this query by myself by updating the AUC function.

```
def auc(y_true, y_pred):
    auc = tf.metrics.auc(y_true, y_pred)[1]
    K.get_session().run(tf.local_variables_initializer())
    return auc
```

Now, this work perfectly fine for me.